# UWP: async read file into byte[]

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I want to read a locally stored file into a byte array. How do I do that? This is my try:

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(filePath);
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
DataReader dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
// doesn't work because ReadBytes wants a byte[] as parameter and also isn't asynchronous
byte[] result = dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer.Length);
```

Comment: [This site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx) mentions that I should use `DataReader`. It is not intended to have a difference. As result I want to have a `byte[]`.

Comment: How do I convert the buffer to a byte[]?

Comment: You're right, I got tripped up again. I find the new API sometimes confusing in its naming.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: For converting from buffer to byte[] I found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/53c8401f-b70a-4c00-93a1-e66862a28035/uwp-replacement-for-systemiofilereadallbytes?forum=wpdevelop). Didn't try it out yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(FILE_NAME);

        byte[] result;
        using (Stream stream = await sampleFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it better to use `CopyToAsync()` for the copy operation?

Answer (score 12):

I think the other answers make things unnecessarily complicated. There is a convenient extension method `IBuffer.ToArray()` for this purpose.

Simply do this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Storage;
...
IStorageFile file;
IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
byte[] bytes = buffer.ToArray();
```

Comment: IBuffer buffer = FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file); needs an await, and where's the ToArray() method?

Comment: Right you are - I have added the await. Regarding the ToArray() it's an extension method defined in System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions, that's why I import that namespace in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Three concepts come to my mind - using *FileStream* and modyfing your method little:

- the first reads bytes via a provided buffer, though this method needs *seekable* stream:

  ```cs
  FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
  picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
  using (Stream fileStr = await (await picker.PickSingleFileAsync()).OpenStreamForReadAsync())
  {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[fileStr.Length];
      const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
      int position = 0;
      int bytesread = 0;
      while ((bytesread = await fileStr.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
         for (int i = 0; i < bytesread; i++, position++)
             bytes[position] = buffer[i];
  }
  ```
- the second method asynchronously copies filestream to memory then gets it as an array:

  ```cs
  using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
  using (Stream fileStr = await (await picker.PickSingleFileAsync()).OpenStreamForReadAsync())
  {
      await fileStr.CopyToAsync(memStream);
      byte[] bytes = memStream.ToArray();
  }
  ```
- your method with little mdification - processing via memory stream:

  ```cs
  var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
  using (MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream())
  {
       await buffer.AsStream().CopyToAsync(mstream);
       byte[] result = mstream.ToArray();
  }
  ```

Or maybe better you can avoid using *byte[]* and instead use *IBuffer* or *MemoryStream*.

Comment: Hey @Romasz, what would drive you to use one of these approaches over the other?

Comment: @AdrianK In fact I would avoid using arrays and go for *Streams*. Choosing the method also depend on platform, predicted file size and its purpose.