# Access to the path, when try to ReadAllTheBytes

Tags: c#, uwp

I am getting a file, via a picker and I am displaying that image in a Image control in xaml.

The image displays perfectly, but when I tried to convert the path to bytes, I get the error

Tried to give picture library permition

```
  var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");

            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file != null) {

                var stream =  await file.OpenReadAsync();

                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

                bitmap.SetSource(stream);

                var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path); // Error

                selectedimage.Source = bitmap;
```

{"Access to the path 'some path' is denied."}

Comment: Thank you @PavelAnikhouski, but I already tried it and it docent work. Besides, what I want to do is convert it into bytes. The image will display, but the app crash on File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path)

Comment: in UWP you should use methods from `FileIO` class

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski, but I wanted to read the bytes

Comment: This is already answered here [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081740/uwp-async-read-file-into-byte) `File.ReadAllBytes` isn't for UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Access to the path, when try to ReadAllTheBytes

UWP run in sandbox, we can't access the file with the path directly,Even though we already add [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability, we could not use `ReadAllTheBytes` under `System.IO` namespace. And Pavel Anikhouski's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081740/uwp-async-read-file-into-byte) is correct, we could use `MemoryStream` to convert the file to bytes.

```
    byte[] result;
    using (Stream stream = await imageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {

            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are my manners, thank you very much, I appreciate it

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: By the way  @Nico how can I get a job an entry level Windows Developer