# Loading file from file picker gives DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am trying to load a file from a unity applications build for UWP, more specific for the HoloLens. I have a working FilePicker

```
#if !UNITY_EDITOR && UNITY_WSA_10_0
        UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async () =>
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bytes");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnAppThread(() => 
            {
                string name = (file != null) ? file.Name : "No data";
                string path = (file != null) ? file.Path : "No data";

                if( file != null )
                    CaseManager.Instance.ActiveUseCase = new Case(new CaseDataDiscriptor(name, path));

                SceneLoader.Instance.LoadSceneAsync("ARViewer");
                SceneLoader.Instance.UnLoadScene("CaseList");

            }, false);
        }, false);
#endif
```

However, when trying to load the file in an other part of the code using

```
File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```

I get following exception, where  is the actual file path of the file. Which exist as I picked it earlier using the file picker

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path <MYPATH>.at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (System.String path) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 at Assets.Scripts.Utils.Parser.Parser.FileToByteArray (System.String filePath) [0x00000] in <000000000000000000000
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Afaik in UWP you can't use anything from `File` directly

Comment: Do you have a workaround for this?

Comment: Afaik you will need to go through [`FileIO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio)

Comment: Can you give an example how should look like if want to load the file as a byte[]

Comment: You would use [`FileIO.ReadBufferAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.readbufferasync#windows-storage-fileio-readbufferasync(windows-storage-istoragefile)) and then simply `ToArray` see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081740/uwp-async-read-file-into-byte)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the file to [FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions?view=winrt-22000) in order to access it later by path (rather than the original Windows.Storage.StorageFile object). If you add it to that list after picking it, all System.IO file access operations should start working.